Make select2 accessible to vimium
I'm building a web app that makes extensive use of select2 drop-downs.
I'm also a vimium user and want select2 inputs to be keyboard accessible.
The standard implementation is:
<input type="text" name="input">
<select name="select></select>
</script>
$("select").select2():
</script>

The problem is that when you hit "f" on the keyboard, vimium lights up all inputs, but not select2 elements.
I tried adding a tabindex to them, but that didn't help.
$('.select2-container').attr('tabindex', 0);

They still don't get found by vimium.
Any ideas out there?
Oddly enough, multi-select select2's do get found by vimium.
